# Creating a list where each list[j] is the character j from each element in another list of strings

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

For example:

```
list1 = ['abc','def','ghi','jk'`] 
output is : list2 = ['adgj','behk','cfi']
```

Basically each element `i` in `list2` should be the ith character in each element of `list1`.

I know the general format would be something along the lines of creating list2 with the following element until the end of each.

```
[list1[0][0]
[list1[0][1]
[list1[0][2]
```

....

However, when I try to create for loops it says that I am out of index and am also struggling with getting the index to stop if the last element in list1 is smaller size than the rest of the elements. I just need some direction on how to set up the for loops?

```
for I in range(Len(list1)):
  list2[I]=list1[I][0]
```

I know I need a second for loop to change for index 0, having trouble implementing that

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Is your example correct? Why does `list2` have `e` twice?

Comment: `from itertools import zip_longest;  result = list(map(''.join, zip_longest(*List1, fillvalue='')))`

Comment: You should iterate over min length list. `for I in range(min(len(list1), len(list2)):`. This should fix the problem

Comment: My mistake made an error in the output. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
list1 = ['abc','def','ghi','jk']

max_length = max(map(len, list1))

result = []
for i in range(max_length):
    element = []
    for s in list1:
        element.append(s[i] if i < len(s) else "")
    result.append(''.join(element))

print(result)
```

The outer loop iterates over all the possible indices, the inner loop iterates over the words, the line:

```
s[i] if i < len(s) else ""
```

retrieves `s[i]` if i is in bounds. Although the most *pythonic* (as mentioned by @juanpa.arrivillaga) way is to do:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']

result = list(map(''.join, zip_longest(*list1, fillvalue='')))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['adgj', 'behk', 'cfi']
```

Albeit, the latter is a bit advanced solution.

Comment: For extra pythonicity, `[''.join(x) for x in zip_longest(*list1, fillvalue='')]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this using `itertools.zip_longest` as [@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291325/creating-a-list-where-each-listj-is-the-character-j-from-each-element-in-anoth#comment102947100_58291325) said in the comments:

```
list(map(''.join, zip_longest(*list1, fillvalue='')))
```

Or manually:

```
result = [''] * max(map(len, list1))
for i in range(len(result)):
    for s in list1:
      if i  < len(s):  result[i] += s[i]
```